# JAVA:Interfaceのキャスト

Tags: java

JAVAにおけるinterfaceのキャストについてです．
下記のようなあるinterfaceを実装したMyClassを定義します．
また，このIntegerをkey,interfaceのリストのArrayListをvalueとする`TreeMap <Integer, ArrayList<MyInterface>>`を戻り値とする関数を与えます．これを用いて得た戻り値を`TreeMap <Integer, ArrayList<MyClass>>`として扱うためのキャストを行いたいのですが，キャストを行うとエラーが出てうまくできません．
方法がわからず困っております，どうぞご教授よろしくお願いします．

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface{...};

class A{
    public A(){
        TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyClass>> myClassListMap 
             = (TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyClass>>) getMyInterfaceListMap();
    }
    TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<MyInterface>> getMyInterfaceListMap(){...};
}
```

Comment: 何が起きているかを把握するために、発生しているエラーメッセージも、記載していただけますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます，キャスト不可能というエラーがでていたのですが，下の方の解答により解決致しました，ありがとうございました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyClass` は `MyInterface` のサブタイプなので、キャスト(ダウンキャスト)が可能です。

```
MyInterface obj1 = .....;
MyClass obj2 = (MyClass)obj1;
```

一方、 `ArrayList<MyClass>` と `ArrayList<MyInterface>` にはそのような関係はないのでキャスト不能です。
例えば、`String`を`Integer`にキャストできないのと同様です。

```
String str = "hello";
Integer num = (Integer)str; // コンパイルエラー

ArrayList<MyInterface> obj = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<MyClass> obj2 = (ArrayList<MyClass>) obj; // コンパイルエラー
```

このような性質を「Javaのジェネリクスは非変である」(下記リンク先参照)と表現したりします。

- [Java ジェネリクスのポイント - Qiita](http://qiita.com/pebblip/items/1206f866980f2ff91e77)

(このリンクの他、多くの方が日本語で解説を書かれています。"generics 共変"といったキーワードで検索し、分かりやすい解説を探してみてください。)

---

質問文中のコード片だけでは真に行いたいことが不明ですが(つまり本来為すべきことはキャストできるようにすることではない、と私は考えているのですが)、もしかしたら行いたいことは次のような形かもしれません:

```
class A<T extends MyInterface> {
    public A() {
       TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<T>> myClassListMap = getMyInterfaceListMap();
    }

    TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList <T>> getMyInterfaceListMap() {...}
}
```

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます！知識が足りずジェネリクスの事自体知りませんでした！調べてみると上手く利用できそうです．非常に助かりました．改めてありがとうございました